# SharePoint Online JSON format phone column to display (555) 444-3333 or 444-3333

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, json, column-formatting, formatting

Brand new to **SharePoint Online** and I want to test out **JSON** to format a telephone column instead of an extra calculated column.

**I'm attempting to display entries:**

**5554443333 as (555) 444-3333**

**and**

**4443333 as 444-3333**

Ideally a number column would be used since the formatting isn't intended to be saved, just displayed.

I'm surprised something like this doesn't already exist in the GitHub PnP formatting examples. Does anyone have examples I can use?

Comment: have you tried the validation 
https://www.sharepointgems.com/2020/05/validate-phone-number-column-in-sharepoint/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm certainly no expert but this code seems to meet your needs. I've only really focused on the "txtContent" field so you can largely ignore the rest.

In plain English, it is counting the length of the string. If it's 10 characters long, it displays it as (xxx) yyy-zzzz, if it is 7 characters, it displays it as xxx-yyyy. If it is neither, it displays "Invalid" but you could easily adapt it to meet any other requirements you may have. This was applied to a column with a type of Number.

Finding the length of the string was an unknown for me but I found this on the [SharePoint Online column formatting guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#detailed-syntax-reference)

> indexOf Since the operator *length* doesn't work for string value types ( it will return 1 or 0 ), indexOf can serve us as a nice workaround to get the length of a string, for instance: indexOf([$column1] + '^', '^'). We will use '^' or any other character we may want to use to find out the end of the string.

My JSON code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": ""
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "line-height": "16px",
        "height": "14px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "",
        "class": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "padding": "0 3px"
      },
      "txtContent": "=if(indexOf(@currentField + '^', '^') == 10,'('+substring(toString(@currentField),0,3)+') '+substring(toString(@currentField),3,6)+'-'+substring(toString(@currentField),6,10),if(indexOf(@currentField + '^', '^') == 7,substring(toString(@currentField),0,3)+'-'+substring(toString(@currentField),3,8),'Invalid')",
      "attributes": {
        "class": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Okay, indexOf... I was trying to use @currentfield.length in all my tests. Any thoughts on why one works but the other doesn't? I'd think .length wouldn't include the commas since it's a number field.

Comment: Looking at the "length" operator in the link above, it says "length: returns the number of items in an array (multi-select person or choice field), for all other value types it returns 1 when true and 0 when false. It does NOT provide the length of a string value "

Answer (score 0):

The JSON code provided by user79408 is feasible

"**indexOf**" can serve us as a nice workaround to **get the length of a string**. E.g：indexOf([$columnname])

Because you choose to use the **Number** column to fill in phone number. And, **every 3 digits in the Number column will add a " `,` " as a separator by default.** Therefore we recommend using `indexOf(@currentField + '^', '^')` to ignore " **`,`**" separator.

[image]

[image]

**JSON Formatting:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": ""
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "line-height": "16px",
        "height": "14px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "",
        "class": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "padding": "0 3px"
      },
      "txtContent": "=if(indexOf(@currentField + '^', '^') == 10,'('+substring(toString(@currentField),0,3)+') '+substring(toString(@currentField),3,6)+'-'+substring(toString(@currentField),6,10),if(indexOf(@currentField + '^', '^') == 7,substring(toString(@currentField),0,3)+'-'+substring(toString(@currentField),3,8),'Please enter a 7-digit or 10-digit phone number!')",
      "attributes": {
        "class": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for the screenshots in your step by step response.