# JSON to make a SharePoint list column accept a phone number and/or an e-mail address and format each appropriately

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I am new to JSON. I am trying to set up a "preferred contact info" column in a SharePoint list. I would like the field to accept a phone number, an e-mail address, or both. When an e-mail address is entered, I would like the column to display a clickable mailto: link. When a phone number is entered, I would like it to be formatted (000) 000-0000. So far I just have the code for e-mail addresses:

```
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json", 

"elmType": "div", 

"children": [ 

    { 

        "elmType": "a", 

        "style": { 

            "padding-right": "8px" 

        }, 

        "txtContent": "@currentField", 

    "attributes": { 

    "target": "_blank", 

    "href": { 

                "operator": "+", 

                "operands": [ 

                    "mailto:", 

                    "@currentField" 

                ] 

            } 

             

        } 

    }, 

    { 

        "elmType": "a", 

        "attributes": { 

    "target":"_blank", 



            "class": "sp-field-quickActions", 

    "href": { 

                "operator": "+", 

                "operands": [ 

                    "mailto:", 

                    "@currentField"


                ] 

            } 

             

        } 

    } 

]
```

Comment: How can JSON identify if it is email or phone number? Is there any specific format / domain being used in email which we can check in JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following JSON

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "8px",
        "display": "=if(indexOf(@currentField,'@') > -1, 'block','none')"
      },
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": {
          "operator": "+",
          "operands": [
            "mailto:",
            "@currentField"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "padding": "0 3px",
        "display": "=if(indexOf(@currentField,'@') > -1, 'none','block')"
      },
      "txtContent": "=if(indexOf(@currentField + '^', '^') == 10,'('+substring(toString(@currentField),0,3)+') '+substring(toString(@currentField),3,6)+'-'+substring(toString(@currentField),6,10),if(indexOf(@currentField + '^', '^') == 7,substring(toString(@currentField),0,3)+'-'+substring(toString(@currentField),3,8),@currentField)",
      "attributes": {
        "class": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In case of Invalid mobile number, I have shown as it is.

Here I have used rules like if value contains "@" then I considered as email. As per Ganesh's comment, if you have fixed domain which you can use to identify whether value is email or not then you can adapt condition according.

Following is output of JSON formatting:

[image]

Reference Link for Mobile Number formatting: [SharePoint Online JSON format phone column to display (555) 444-3333 or 444-3333](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297719/sharepoint-online-json-format-phone-column-to-display-555-444-3333-or-444-3333)

Please mark this as answer it it does help to you.